# DataTable rows not fetched after adding new row

Tags: c++, mysql, .net, datatable

I added a new row and updated the datatable. The record was inserted into the table. But when I filled with the same datatable again, the result is an empty datatable. Am I missing something? Did I do something wrong? I just learned about using database in .net recently and I don't know what to do with this problem.

```
MySqlConnection ^connection;
DataTable ^table1;
MySqlDataAdapter ^adapter1;
MySqlCommandBuilder ^cmb;


private: System::Void opentable(String ^sql){
        adapter1 = gcnew MySqlDataAdapter(sql,connection);
        cmb = gcnew MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter1);
        table1 = gcnew DataTable;
        adapter1->Fill(table1);
}
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    connection = gcnew MySqlConnection("XXXXXXXXXX");
    connection->Open();
}

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    opentable("SELECT * FROM ms_per WHERE PerCode='001'");

    if(table1->Rows->Count==0){    //table1->Rows->Count is 0
        DataRow ^newrow = table1->NewRow();
        newrow["PerCode"] = "001";
        table1->Rows->Add(newrow);
    }
    adapter1->Update(table1);

    opentable("SELECT * FROM ms_perhist");
    dataGridView1->DataSource=table1;
    //ms_perhist is not an empty table, but after this the DataTable is empty.
```

I am seeing if I can wrap these lines into a single procedure so I can use it with other tables/queries:

```
        adapter1 = gcnew MySqlDataAdapter(sql,connection);
        cmb = gcnew MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter1);
        table1 = gcnew DataTable;
        adapter1->Fill(table1);
```

**Note 1**: I tried the following line. Data in ms_perhist shows up correctly, so the newrow-update lines may have something to do with the problem.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    opentable("SELECT * FROM ms_per WHERE PerCode='001'");
    opentable("SELECT * FROM ms_perhist");
    dataGridView1->DataSource=table1;
}
```

Comment: still looking for that rowcount Red? Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition or 2015 ok?

Comment: Ah yes. I was wondering if no one understands my problem.
The problem is not rowcount anymore. It's the empty datatable.

Comment: well I will take a look. It may be a different environment than the one you are using.

Comment: I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. Maybe you can try with c# or vb if they are more comfortable, as long as it's in .net. I think it's more likely that I am doing something wrong like reusing the DataTable or not freeing it. I was thinking about wrapping the 4 lines around adapter1->Fill into a procedure.

Comment: I tried with C#. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was using an outdated MySQL.Data.dll. I checked the modified date and it was from 2008.

I changed the MySQL Connector version to the most recent version and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in c# and it's working fine. May be C++ creating new datable instance when you are executing the following line

```
table1 = gcnew DataTable;
```

So don't use that line twice in your code. But I am not sure about C++

Comment: I'm thinking about wrapping the 4 lines above `adapter1->Fill(table1)` into a procedure, so I can use it with other tables/queries. But without `table1 = gcnew DataTable` the datatable structure would not update